# Enabling disabled submit button doesn't work during filling the field which is required to enable the submit

Tags: submit, form-submit

sorry if the title isn't clear, i was trying to explain in the best possible way. The situation I have is the following: I have a newsletter with a submit button. I have used jquery to unlock the SUBMIT button after the correct email is typed in. It is working fine apart of one thing - I have to click anywhere outside the field (not on the submit button) to enable the submit, then on submit. There was something I have to add somewhere around this line i think, but I dont know what:

```
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
```

the full code is here:

HTML:

```
<div class="element">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Enter your email" />
</div>           

<div id="bsubmit">
    <input name="submit" id="submit" src="_images/generic/send_button.png?submit+button=" type="image" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

and jq:

```
$.fn.swapText = function(){
return this.each(function(){
    var tmpDefVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).css('color', '#999');

    $(this).focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() == tmpDefVal){
            $(this)
                .css('color', '#000')
                .val('');
        }
    });

    $(this).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this)
                .css('color', '#999')
                .val(tmpDefVal);
        }
    });

});
```

}

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#email').swapText();

$('#email').change(function(){
    var regexp = /^\w+[@]\w+\.\w{2}$/;

    if(regexp.test($(this).val())){
        $(this).removeClass('err');
        $(this).addClass('ok');
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('ok');
        $(this).addClass('err');
    }
});
```

});

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you have two elements with an id of submit.

Comment: Thanks Lyn Headley. You were right with this duplicated ID. this also was a problem. more my oversight, however this didn't cause a problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I hope it is something easy. Any other spots which can help me with this one? Thank you in advance